# No OS found, after installing Ubuntu on my Sony Vaio

Tags: boot, system-installation

I installed the newest Ubuntu on my Sony Vaio. Now, It can not boot.

I get this on screen:

```
Yukon PXE v6.65.1.1 (alpha) (20090623)
© Copyright 2003-2009 Marvell ®. All rights reserved.
Pre-boot eXecution Environment (PXE) v2.1
© Copyright 1997-2000 Intel Corporation
PXE-E61: Media test failure, check cable
PXE-M0F: Exiting PXE ROM
```

Then it tells me:

> No OS found

Comment: Enter the BIOS. Select first device to boot HDD. Disable PXE boot.

Comment: You do actually have ubuntu installed? or it says when try to boot from a bootable device (Like usb or external hard drive).

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure that you have ubuntu installed **compeletely**. 
Has the ubuntu boot entry been added to the MBR?

Answer (score -1):

So you tried to install ubuntu, replacing windows? You may have been running it off of the USB, instead of installing it on your HDD/SSD, which would cause the computer to be unable to boot if you unplugged the USB. If so, try plugging any USBs that you had plugged in at the time of install back in and try to reboot.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Pilot6 I'm sorry, but I couldn't help but notice that the "answer" underneath mine is much less helpful, as at least with mine, you can fill in the rest yourself and try to plug the USB back in, as with MadShaw's, it is only clarification.